# Printing two pages in SSRS using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am working on a project where a button is clicked in a program and a two page duplex report that is in SSRS prints out. I have gotten it to the point where I get one of the two pages to print but not the duplex page. I know I need to set e.HasMorePages to true and put in an index. The problem is when it goes to page two it errors because of the metafile. I'm not sure how to get around this.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
Public Class Printing

Dim pages As New List(Of Metafile)
Dim pageIndex As Integer = 0
Dim doc As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument()
Dim ReportViewer1 As New ReportViewer
Dim TotalQTY As Int32
Dim data() As Byte   
Dim receiveText As String


    Private Sub Printing_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'receiveText = Command()

        receiveText = "08NFA-0000"

        With ReportViewer1
            .Visible = False
            .ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote
            .ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Traveler/Traveler"
            .ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New _
                     Uri("http://sql01/ReportServer_MADE2MANAGE")
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(ReportViewer1)

        Dim doc As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument()
        doc = New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument()
        AddHandler doc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintPageHandler
        Dim dialog As New PrintDialog()
        dialog.Document = doc

        doc.PrinterSettings.Duplex = System.Drawing.Printing.Duplex.Vertical

        Dim deviceInfo As String =
            "<DeviceInfo>" &
            "<OutputFormat>emf</OutputFormat>" &
            "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" &
            "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" &
            "  <MarginTop>0.125in</MarginTop>" &
            "  <MarginLeft>0.125in</MarginLeft>" &
            "  <MarginRight>0.125in</MarginRight>" &
            "  <MarginBottom>0.125in</MarginBottom>" &
            "</DeviceInfo>"

        Dim warnings() As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Warning
        Dim streamids() As String
        Dim mimeType, encoding, filenameExtension As String
        mimeType = "" : encoding = "" : filenameExtension = ""

        Dim Parm As New ReportParameter("JobOrder", receiveText)

        Dim parmSO1(0) As ReportParameter

        parmSO1(0) = Parm

        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parmSO1)

        data = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("Image",
                  deviceInfo, mimeType, encoding, filenameExtension,
                  streamids, warnings)
        pages.Add(New Metafile(New MemoryStream(data)))

        For Each pageName As String In streamids
            data = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.RenderStream("Image",
                   pageName, deviceInfo, mimeType, encoding)
            pages.Add(New Metafile(New MemoryStream(data)))
        Next
        doc.Print()
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintPageHandler(ByVal sender As Object,
       ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)

        Dim page As Metafile = pages(pageIndex)

        pageIndex += 1
        Dim pWidth As Integer = 910
        Dim pHeight As Integer = 1500
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(page, 0, 0, pWidth, pHeight)
        e.HasMorePages = pageIndex < pages.Count

    End Sub


End Class
```